# Convert Spring Boot Project to classical static Spring Project

Tags: java

I'm currently looking for a tool or framework which converts a Spring Boot project with a bunch of conditional beans (auto-configurations etc. which are all evaluated during runtime) into a classical Spring Project with "static" configurations (no conditionals, no beans evaluated during runtime).

Is there anything I can use to do this?